# SMO 2013 Junior First Round Q35.

Tags: number-theory

In a competition that i have recently taken part in, one of this questions popped out:
$2^{29}$ has nine distinct digits. Find the digit that is not in the sequence.
My answer will be placed as a 'Answer-your-question'. 
However, my main question is: are there other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Most people did the same as me: 
Since closed to nothing would do. There was only one thing to do. **SMACK** the question with plain and good-ol' Brute-force.
From that, we now know that the answer is 4.